# How to synchronously wait the Result callback from Android to Flutter using the invokeMethod?

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to synchronously call some Flutter methods from Android (Java) using the Flutter MethodChannel.

```
    invokeMethod(String method, @Nullable Object arguments, MethodChannel.Result callback)
```

I already tried CountDownLatch, locks and even Threads but would just stop after calling the countdown await or synchronize(lock) or even thread.join.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        // code/methods initializations..

        public String testData(){
            final String[] result = new String[1];
            final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

            flutterMethods.invokeMethod("getString", "abcdefg", new MethodChannel.Result() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(Object o) {
                               result[0] = o.toString();
                               Log.e(TAG,"success);
                               latch.countDown(); 
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void error(String s, String s1, Object o) {
                               latch.countDown(); 
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void notImplemented() {
                               latch.countDown(); 
                        }
            }

            Log.e(TAG,"about to wait forever!"); 
            latch.await();
            Log.e(TAG,"done!");
            return result[0];
    }
```

Of course, this will work asynchronously without the waits, but I want to make this into a synchronous library function at some point. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done.

Flutter architecture is unique in the sense that communication with the OS always asynchronous.

The principle is that Flutter and the native side sends messages to each others by both listening to the same port on the device.
This allows increased performances as there is no "language bridge" but comes at the cost of being forced to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is a really terrible idea and you likely shouldn't do it. Callbacks are fine in 99% of use cases.

If you still really want to though, a simple way would be to just use a `while(!messageRecieved) { // do something }` style loop. The key important factor here is that you can't *actually* suspend the thread, because if you do it will be unable to receive any messages.

If you don't want to cause unneeded CPU usage, you could try to do a small IO operation in the body of the loop.